# Apple MacBook Pro display shows black screen

Tags: macbook-pro, display

I have a MacBook Pro 15 inch 2015 model. Until yesterday it worked fine. But now it shows a black screen. But when I connect to external display through HDMI it works fine.

[image: Below is the image for macbook which shows black screen and I can observe only caps button works on the keyboard.]

[image: So, I am trying to re-install mac os x ei.]

Is there any solution to solve that problem?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunatly, it looks like a hardware issue.

Use the external monitor to see what you are doing and go to the system preferences and check the settings. Check the monitor preferences and see if it listed. Try turning the brightness all the way up.

If it is a 2015 model and less than 1 year old Apple should repair it for free. If you have AppleCare extended warranty they will repair it for 3 years for free. Take it to an Apple Store or an Apple approved repair vendor.

Comment: Can I replace my laptop at icare

Comment: I have never heard of icare but if it is under warranty then Apple will repair if for free.

Comment: Sorry its not icare its apple care... Can i ask for replacement... Will the give new one... It is under warranty and i bought it on july

Comment: Apple gets the choice of whether to repair or replace. You can ask for a new computer but normally they will just repair yours.

Answer (score -1):

It's display cable problem dude check cable connector by opening display case

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different and taking the time to post an answer!  It's helpful to *expand* on your answer to further explain/clarify what you are attempting to communicate.  It also helps to explain why your answer is right and be sure to include citations and references.